# AngularJS - Important data on view requiring sync call

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, asynchronous, promise

Suppose I want to build a page similar to the Facebook wall.

I want to include a button on the top of the page, same as Facebook does, which indicates whether the current user we are viewing is our friend (in this case the button will show "Friends"), or the user we are viewing isn't our friend (in this case the button will show "Add Friend").

I have to show this button with the appropriate text("Friends" or "Add Friend") as the page loads and I can't wait too much, otherwise the user might see this button shows few seconds after the page loads. When you view a Facebook wall you never see this button shows few seconds after the page loads but immediately as it loads - I want the same functionality.

How can I make sure the button will show as the page loads (and not few seconds after) without using sync call? It seems like promises and others techniques might get the data fast enough from the server before the page loads but can I trust it for sure ? What will happen in case the server is too slow and the database query won't finish fast enough?

Just to make sure we are on the same line, the text "Friends" or "Add Friend" is determined by an http call to the server, waiting for the query to be done and afterwards return the value back to the client (via callback).

Thank you,

SynD

Comment: you can pre-render it on server side so it will be already shown after the page loads.

Comment: Oh... Seems like a good idea. I think I misused the AngularJS framework. I will try it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you need certain data immediately available upon page load, render a `<script>` block into your HTML output and put data into a global variable, which you can then access in your Angular code.